# Pyplot/Matplotlib: How to access figures opened by another interpreter?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib.pyplot` (with Eclipse on Windows). Every time I run my code it opens several pyplot figure windows.

The problem is that if I don't close those windows manually they accumulate. I would like to use pyplot to find those windows (opened by another process of python.exe) and re-use them. In other words, I do not want to have multiple windows for the same figure, even across interpreter processes.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to reuse plot windows if you must use eclipse to run it.  When I am working interactively with matplotlib, I use either spyder or ipython.  Edit class, reload class, and run code again. If you just want to get rid of all the open plot windows, hit the stacked stop icons to kill all your runing python instances.